# Trouble pushing changes to remote Git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have started learning Ruby on Rails and Git.

Whenever I try to push any changes to my remote repo on Github, I encounter the following error:

```
C:\Sites\first>git push origin master
To git@github.com:piy9/Twitter_clone.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:piy9/Twitter_clone.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

NOte: I have added all the files in the directory and committed the changes. I have not created any separate branches using pull or checkout.

I am not asking for a solution to the problem.

doing

```
git push -f or
git push origin +HEAD
```

worked for me.

What I want to know is, why am I getting the error while trying to push to the original branch.

Comment: This link might help: [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/)

Comment: May be you have to do git pull and try it again

Answer (score 0):

**follow this and get everything works.**...

```
git branch production
git checkout production
#do some code changes
git commit -am "some desparate code changes to try fix heroku"
git push heroku production:master
```

Note: **this will get your work done and will leave your previous branch.**

or you can try this one also `git push heroku +master`

Comment: Not trying to deploy it to heroku directly. First I am trying to make some changes to the remote repo on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like remote branch is ahead of yours, which means it contains something your local branch does not have. You may easily see commits on remote branch since when local branch was created or updated (assuming you run "git fetch origin/master" to fetch remote changes first):

```
git diff HEAD...origin/master
```

The output will answer your question why you are getting the error.

Now, my guess about the reason of the problem you have is that either someone has access to remote and pushed something, or you modified something using github editing interface and committed since last checkout/pull/merge. Using forced push as you did is not a good approach and it messes the history, it basically overwrites the remote branch with your copy, ignoring any remote changes.

Comment: I am the only one working on the project.

I created an empty repo on the github website and then was trying to push the local data to the remote one.

Comment: @Piyush then do diff and see what stops remote side accepting your push. Might it be then new project creation added GPL licence or readme file commit, which your local branch does not have.